# Why this bootstrap button is misbehaving?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

[image: Misbehaving button]

Expected behaviour: The button should have appeared on the right side and the nav titles on the left.

```
  <nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">CANDY</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks">
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-colllapse" id="navLinks">
  <ul class="navbar-nav">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a href="" class="nav-link">TICKETS</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If the parent is a CSS Flexbos, then you can take advantage of the Flexbox ability to **change the order of appearance** of flexbox child items. Although, in this case since all child elements carry the same classes, its not easy to select them and set an order to something like `.navTripleLineIcon {order:1}` and `.navTextButtons {order:2}`

Comment: It seems you are bootstrap and I see some errors in your code. Check boostrap documentation for navbar examples and use the code from those

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="collapse navbar-colllapse" id="navLinks">
```

In this line, collapse is misspelt by having three ls. Such errors are pretty common and go undetected. Correcting the spelling resolves the issue.